# How can I split a line into two lines if the length is greater than 7 using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

For example I just wanted to print something like this in the command line. Let say I have a file called file.txt.

```
 What is life?
 how are you?
 hi
 whatup
 this is more than
```

And I want to print it out on the command line using awk but if the number of characters is greater than 7, then the output should look like this.

```
 What is 
 life?
 how are 
 you?
 hi
 whatup
 this is
 more than
```

So basically when I use awk if the number of characters is greater than 7 it split the line into two lines on the output.

Comment: Why does your last line of desired output have `more than`, which is 9 characters? Shouldn't this be `more` and `than` as two separate lines?

Comment: does a "long" line only get split/wrapped *once*, or should it continue to be wrapped until it is <= 7 characters long?

Answer (score 12):

While you can do this in `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.{8}/,"&\n"); print}' file
What is
life?
how are
you?
hi
whatup
this is
more than
```

it really isn't the best tool for the job. You could do the same thing more simply with:

```
$ fold -sw 8 file
What is 
life?
how are 
you?
hi
whatup
this is 
more 
than
```

You could also use Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.{8}/$&\n/' file
What is 
life?
how are 
you?
hi
whatup
this is 
more than
```

Comment: The `fold` one didn't satisfy the OP requirement..

Comment: @cuonglm actually, the fold is the only one that is religiously satisfying the requirements, [I call the example misleading](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282739/how-can-i-split-a-line-into-two-lines-if-the-length-is-greater-than-7-using-awk#comment492173_282739)

Comment: @Braiam: The OP said "splitting the line into two lines", `fold` will split the lines into as many lines as it can.

Comment: @cuonglm and OP didn't specify if it's recursive or not. We can presume any. BTW, at least 2 out 6 solutions presented do so.

Comment: @Braiam, ah. So that rule of splitting the line at most once could explain the final line being `more than`.

Comment: Including an space will ensure that awk breaks the line only once ending on an (existing) space: `awk '{sub(/.{1,8} /,"&\n"); print}' file`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `awk`, as offered in other answers, but you could also use `fmt`

```
fmt -s -w8 file
What is
life?
how are
you?
hi
whatup
this
is more
than
```

Answer (score 2):

with

```
awk 'length < 7 { print ; next ; } 
         { printf "%s\n%s\n",substr($0,0,7),substr($0,8) }' file.txt
```

result is

```
What is
 life?
how are
 you?
hi
whatup
this is
 more than
```

to skip white char use

```
awk 'length < 7 { print ; next ; } 
    { printf "%s\n",substr($0,0,7) ; 
      i=8 ; while (substr($0,i,1) == " " ) i++; printf "%s\n",substr($0,i) }'
```

Comment: The question says "if the number of characters is *greater than* 7".  This answer will "split" a line that is exactly 7 characters long into one line with 7 characters and another with 0 characters.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired output with `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/.\{7\} /&\
/' <file
What is 
life?
how are 
you?
hi
whatup
this is 
more than
```

Because the 8th character in your input is always space, then that did the trick.

If you want to break at 7th character regardless of 8th one:

```
$ sed -e 's/./\
&/8' <file
```

Comment: The question asked for a solution with awk.

Comment: There is no stated rule that the 8 character will always be an space ` `.

Comment: Your solution executes a hard break at the 8th character. It will fail if the a line is `Why is life?`, for example.

Comment: The question says "if the number of characters is *greater than* 7". This answer (the second one) will "split" a line that is exactly 7 characters long into one line with 7 characters and another with 0 characters.

Comment: @G-Man: Good point, see my updated one.